# Ономатопея слова "блювати"

Tags: ономатопея

Як передати на письмі звуки блювання?

Comment: Zazvıćaj ce _bue_ abo _bve_ [sxoźe na kaljku z anglijsjkoji _bleah_, odnak ne fakt], ale ne baću akademićnıx ʒ́erel, tomu treba daljê kopatı abo zbıratı materijalı.

Comment: "Буе" або "Бее" як варіант